# Issue in launching Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I launch simple application on the AVD I am getting following Error

> "Target device: Nexus_6_API_23 [emulator-5554] Installing APK:
>   D:\AndroidStudioProjects\SamApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.home.pradeep.samapp Installing
>   com.home.pradeep.samapp DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/com.home.pradeep.samapp" Aborted "

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure your your emulator was fully loaded whan you run the app?

Comment: Thanks, Its resolved it was not loaded.